# Why am I getting address sanitiser iterating through string?

Tags: c++, string, overflow, address-sanitizer

I am answering this question https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/

Compiler show this error when it is case "){" and "]"

```
class Solution {
public:
bool isValid(string s) {
    stack<char> q;
    char ch;

    for(auto& ch : s){
        if(ch == ')' && q.top() == '(' && !q.empty()){
            q.pop();
        }
        else if(ch == '}' && q.top() == '{' && !q.empty()){
            q.pop();
        }
        else if(ch == ']' && q.top() == '[' && !q.empty()){
            q.pop();
        }
        else{
            q.push(ch);
        }
        
    }
    
    return q.empty();
}
```

};

Comment: `if(ch == ')' && q.top()` -- What if the stack is empty?  What will `q.top()` give you?  And your check for empty is too late -- the damage has been already done.

Comment: This is also why using sites such as LeetCode to learn C++ is a waste of time.  That site is there for *experienced* C++ programmers who have time to answer some random puzzle questions.  An experienced C++ programmer would know right away to test for an empty stack *first*, or at the very least, see the error immediately and without help from StackOverflow, make the correction.  To learn C++ properly requires peer-reviewed books and materials, not puzzle websites.

Comment: The address sanitizer tells you the line where the problem occured, so you have to separate all checks in the `if` to see that the `q.top()` is the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/5vh6zjc6f

Comment: Thx!! I didn't notice that . Seems like it would have undifined behavior, propably the reason the loop won't end.